# Eigen problem with constrained (equal) eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

Let $\Omega$ be a symmetric and positive definite matrix. From a test of hypothesis I know that some eigenvalues are likely to be equal (the test also suggests which eigenvalues). Do you have any suggestions for obtaining the matrix, say $\tilde{\Omega}$, that can be obtained by fixing those eigenvalues to be equal? In other words, I would expect a matrix, quite "close" to $\Omega$, but not exactly the same.

Any suggestions is really appreciated.

Comment: So you are looking for the closest matrix to a given one with repeated eigenvalues? How many? In which metric?

Comment: Hi Federico, it is exactly the point. Actually, a priori I don't know how many eigenvalues are equal. I am interested in a very general strategy for obtaining such $\tilde{\Omega}$, any metric could be justifiable.

Comment: This sounds more like a modelling problem. What do you know, apart from the matrix entries? Do you have a 'typical' level of noise, for instance? What would you do if the eigenvalues are logarithmically distributed, e.g., $diag(1, 1.1, 1.11, 1.111, 1.11111, ...)$?

Comment: I don't know anything more that the matrix $\Omega$. Essentially, it is an estimated covariance matrix of a multivariate model. But if some eigenvalues are equal, I might have problems in terms of identification of certain parameters of the model bla bla bla. Let a statistical test says $k$ eigenvalues, that look like very similar, are effectively equivalent (from a statistical point of view). I would like to see the consequences on my identification problem when the eigenvalues are exactly the same. For this reason, I would like to work with the "closest" matrix to the original $\Omega$.

Comment: But then your test tells you $k$, at least? So the problem is, given $k$ and $\Omega$, find the closest matrix to $\Omega$ (in some metric) with $k$ repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, the test suggests $k$, and those eigenvalues that are (statistically) equal. Specifically, I know these eigenvalues are equal (each other), but I don't know to which value. My first idea was to fix these eigenvalues to their mean and start an iterative algorithm, substantially based on repeating the suggestion made by Louis here below. However, I don't know whether it is stable and whether it returns the closest matrix to $\Omega$ according to some metric.

Comment: What kind of iterative algorithm do you plan to start once you have set those close eigenvalues to their mean? At that point diagonalizing $\tilde{\Omega}$ will give you back the same eigenvectors and eigenvalues, so I don't think there are further improvements that you can make.

Comment: Algebraically, the repeated eigenvalue is present iff the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial $f(t)$ of $\Omega$ vanishes identically. It means that $f$ and $f'$ have a common root. More generally,  eigenvalue repeats $k$ times iff $f$ and its $k$th derivative $f^{(k)}$ have a common root. One doesn't need roots, of course, one can use resultants instead.

Answer (score 1):

The average (centroid) $\lambda = \frac{\lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_k}{k}$ minimizes the sum of squared differences $f(\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^k (\lambda - \lambda_i)^2$.

This suggests an algorithm, which is essentially what Louis Deaett suggests, if I understand correctly:

- compute the diagonalization $\Omega = V\Lambda V^{-1}$.
- permute eigenvalues and eigenvectors so that the sum of squared distances from the centroid $f(\lambda)$ is minimized by the first $k$ eigenvalues. It is not clear how to do this step in optimal time, even if the solution may be evident in the 'eyeball norm' in many practical cases.
- replace those $k$ eigenvalues with their mean, to obtain $\tilde{\Omega} = V\tilde{\Lambda}V^{-1}$.

I conjecture that this algorithm gives you the optimal answer in the Frobenius norm $\|\Omega - \tilde{\Omega}\|_F^2 =  \sum_{i,j} (\Omega_{ij} - \tilde{\Omega}_{ij})^2$; based on experience on similar problems, it looks like [Weyl's inequalities for eigenvalues](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/weyl-inequalities/) could be used to give a proof.

Comment: Dear Federico, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I will try to provide a proof for this intuitive result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but your positive definite (symmetric) matrix is going to be diagonalized by some unitary matrix $U$.  So $U^*\Omega U=\Lambda$ for some diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ of its eigenvalues.  This gives $U\Lambda U^*= \Omega$.

It sounds like perhaps what you are after is $\tilde\Omega=U\tilde\Lambda U^*$, where the difference between $\Lambda$ and $\tilde\Lambda$ is that in $\tilde\Lambda$, the two eigenvalues that were ``close'' have been replaced by two values that are equal.

Comment: Thanks Louis for your reply. This was my first strategy to attack the problem. For sure, it is very simple and fast, but it is based on fixing the eigenvalues that are potentially equal to a value that I don't know. If from the statistical test I get the result that $k$ eigenvalues are equal, what shoud I do, fixing them to the average of these $k$ eigenvalues? Maybe, an iterative procedure could help in soving the problem, but I was wondering whether there was some analytical result in matrix algebra. Or maybe, some specific algorithm already treated in the literature.

Comment: To your question, yes I think that is the thing left to determine, and it may depend on your application/context.  The gist of Federico Poloni's answer is to choose this value so as to minimize the norm difference of your $\Omega$ and your $\tilde\Omega$, which is a natural idea.  If you have more information from your application, then maybe something different makes sense.  For example, maybe the application suggests that the two eigenvalues should not be given equal weight?  I'm speculating, but there probably isn't more to say in full generality than what Federico has pointed out.